# Multiple variables in Verilog case structure control expression

Tags: syntax, verilog

I am using case statement to write my Verilog logic. I wanted to know if we can AND multiple variables in the case's control expression.

```
reg a;
reg [5:0] b;
reg c;
case(a & b)
    1'b0 & 6'd0: c <= 1'b1;
    1'b1 & 6'd1: c <= 1'b0;
    default: c <= 1'b0;
endcase
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a *concatenation* `{}` not *and* `&`

```
case({a,b})
    {1'b0 , 6'd0}: c <= 1'b1;
    {1'b1 , 6'd1}: c <= 1'b0;
    default: c <= 1'b0;
endcase
```

Comment: What is the guideline for using {} over &, is there any synthesis issue that props up?

Comment: It is not a question of one over the other--they are different operators with different behaviors. You need to choose the operator that gives you the behavior you need.